# WordPress plugin add constructed stylesheet with display none in a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a plugin but when I reload the page it appears constructed stylesheet, if I access it for the first time or reload with ctr + f5 it does not appear.

I have searched all the plugin code for some creation with CSSStyleSheet or createElement ("style"), but there is nothing.

How could I debug or search with the inspector what part of the code is generating this?

```
*constructed stylesheet*
.dc-ad {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You have to be clearer about your problem to get help... Provide some code, so we can see how you are using this plugin and what it does. Better yet, just say "I'm using a wordpress plugin called XYZ and it behaves like this..." it's much more likely that some user have worked with it before and know the issue.

Comment: It is a core plugin of a theme that I am customizing, but I would like to know a way to locate where the constructed stylesheet is generated or inserted.

How can I get it with chrome debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely an ad blocker. It detects the "ad" part in the CSS class and changes it to `display: none !important`